# Override htacces rule only for specific directory

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a WordPress site with ithemes security installed plugin. I want to disable this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^$" [NC,OR]
```

only for this `wp-content/uploads/xmls` directory.

Relevant (summarised) section of `.htaccess` file:

```
# Begin HackRepair.com Blacklist
RewriteEngine on
# Abuse Agent Blocking
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^[Ww]eb[Bb]andit [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Acunetix [NC,OR]
:
: etc.
:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} YisouSpider [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} zermelo [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ZyBorg
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
# Abuse bot blocking rule end
```

Comment: The `RewriteCond` directive is just a _condition_ that applies to another rule, it's not in itself a "rule". What is the complete rule?

Comment: The complete rule is in this file http://pastebin.com/5Hw9KZnW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To effectively disable that *condition* for that one URL-path, you will need to add another rule immediately before the rule in question. ie. *before* the `# Abuse Agent Blocking` comment.

For example:

```
# Allow an empty User-Agent for requests that start "/wp-content/uploads/xmls"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/xmls - [S=1]

# Abuse Agent Blocking
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^[Ww]eb[Bb]andit [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Acunetix [NC,OR]
: etc.
```

The first rule *skips* the following rule if the requested URL-path starts `/wp-content/uploads/xmls` and the `User-Agent` header is empty. So, it effectively bypasses the rule that would otherwise block it.

This does assume that the request maps to a physical file in that directory. ie. Not a request that would otherwise be rewritten to the WordPress front-controller (`index.php`).